# Why referring to immutable variable is NOT side effect free in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

The code below won't compile because of the reference to the `let one = 1`.

Why? It seems like it's side effect free (and thread safe too) - as it's impossible to change the immutable data.

[playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2KEA)

```
let one = 1
func one_plus(v: int): int =
  one + v
  
echo one_plus(2)
```

Does code like that - referring to external immutable data - supposed to be written somehow differently in Nim to be considered side-effect free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is the problem is using the global namespace, wrapping your code into a proc makes it compile and run:

```
proc main() =
  let one = 1
  func one_plus(v: int): int =
    one + v
    
  echo one_plus(2)

main()
```

If you still want to use a global, you need to use [const section](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#statements-and-expressions-const-section):

```
const one = 1
func one_plus(v: int): int =
  one + v
  
echo one_plus(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if a variable is immutable, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's free of side-effects.

Consider this example:

```
type A = ref object
  i: int

let one = A(i: 2)
proc one_plus(v: int): int =
  one.i += v
  one.i

echo one.i
echo one_plus(2)
echo one.i
```

https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3zRB

Output:

```
2
4
4
```

`let one` stores the `ref` pointer to memory address and you can't change it (the pointer). But after dereferencing it, I can change underlying object's data even though the variable was declared as `let`.